# How to manage core data in a alternate class?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

**This is .h file as I have declared**

```
     @protocol CoreData <NSObject>

    -(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;

    @end


    @interface coreData : NSObject
    {
        id<CoreData> delegate;
    }

    @property (retain)id delegate;
    @property (readonly,strong ,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    @property (readonly,strong ,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    @property (readonly,strong ,nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistStoreCoordinator;

    -(void)saveContext;
    -(NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
    @end
```

**This is .m file**

```
@implementation coreData

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistStoreCoordinator = _persistStoreCoordinator;

-(void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if(managedObjectContext !=nil)
    {
        if([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]){

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
#pragma mark -core data stack

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if(_managedObjectContext !=nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator =[self persistStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator !=nil)
    {
        _managedObjectContext=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if(_managedObjectModel !=nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Superallocation" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel =[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistStoreCoordinator
{
    if(_persistStoreCoordinator !=nil)
    {
        return _persistStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeURL =[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SuperantZ.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if([_persistStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"unresolved error %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _persistStoreCoordinator;
}
-(NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Questions:

1. How to declare core data in view controller not in AppDelegate class?
2. While using this code in AppDelegate its working why?
3. After I place in the normal class it is giving me error

   `like=[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]`

Answer (score 0):

> 2.while using this code in AppDelegate its working why?
>
> 3.After i place in the normal class its giving me error like=[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]

There's your answer - it still thinks the code is in the app delegate.

This

```
[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]
```

should be

```
[coreData managedObjectContext]
```

And everything needs to be wired up  properly for this to work.

Incidentally, calling a class 'coreData' is pretty horrible. I'll forget about the missing capital letter (Obj-C classes traditionally start with a capital to reinforce that they are classes), the reason I point it out is you are using the name of something that already exists (bar one letter) and could become insanely confusing down the line.

2 suggestions
Rename the class to something sensible.
Make the class a singleton that can be called from anywhere.